# Eclipse debugger not stopping in JUnit Breakpoints in Java 7

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, junit

I realize there were a bunch of these questions a few years ago.  But those problems were fixed an update to Java 6.  But I'm on Java 7.

I'm on a Mac OS X, Java 7, everything is up to date.

Things I've tried:

- Project Clean
- In the debug config, I tried telling it to not run in the background.
- In the debug config, tried both running all tests in class and just running a specific test
- Double checked jar files and project config

The unit tests DO run, they just don't pause for debugging.

Update:

If I set a breakpoint in the *grandparent* class SolrTestCasJ4, which is in a second project open in the workspace, AND change the debug config from running a method to run all, it stops near the top of one of my test methods.  But it only for an initial breakpoint in the grandparent class.  I guess that's an OK workaround for now, but a bit weird and not really an explanation.

Comment: You did run using "Debug", not "Run", right?

Comment: i had similar problems in combination with maven. are the class files generated from your source files or is it maybe an old artifact?

Comment: @Thilo thanks for double checking, but yes, using Debug

Comment: @PhilippSander Not using Maven for this project, sadly all ant at this time.  The *base* class of the unit test is from a second project in the workspace, though I suppose jar files for it might be hanging around as well (previously wasn't using second project, added it later, thought Eclipse would give it precedence), so I'll check that.

Comment: @PhilippSander I did sort out the jar file stuff, I believe it's all set now, but still seeing odd behavior.  I've updated the question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you're Eclipse instance isn't the one running tomcat. Sometimes eclipse will crash and your server is still running. When you reopen eclipse you can run your tests, but the breakpoints